# Speed up Embedded Groovy in Java

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to create scripted AI for a game engine I'm working on for fun. I decided to try to use Groovy to create .groovy behavior files which are loaded in as GroovyClasses and then cast to my behavior interface. The problem is, is that this is incredibly slow. I'm performing the updates each game cycle and the scripted AI classes bring the program to a crawl. My question is, is there a way to speed up embedded groovy speed or is there a better way to do what I am doing? Thanks for any help.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public interface Behavior {
     public void execute(GameComponent component, float time);
}
```

The Groovy files are loaded at init time and are cast GroovyClasses:

```
 public boolean cacheScript(String key, String path) {

        try {
            Class groovyClass = loader.parseClass(ClassLoader
                    .getSystemResourceAsStream(path));
            Object object = groovyClass.newInstance();
            scripts.put(key, (Behavior) object);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            return false;
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Then a GameComponent executes this code like this

```
engine.getBehavior(key).execute(component, time);
```

Comment: Can I ask what you gain in having these behaviour files in groovy? Is there some sort of dynamic editing you need?

Comment: Are you sure that the groovy code you are executing are doing things you could expect to be fast? Maybe the code is just slow and it's not the fault of it being groovy script code.

Comment: @java drinker I don't really 'need' anything right now. This is all just for fun. I am mostly working my way through this book http://www.amazon.com/Artificial-Intelligence-Kaufmann-Interactive-Technology/dp/0124977820 and they had a section on scripted AI and I wanted to play around with groovy. They were talking about lua (similar to how WOW lets you create add-ons...) so I thought groovy would be a good fit for scripted AI.

Comment: @buhb, well i created some junit tests and did some profiling of just loading the cached object and then executing it many times. It is noticeably slower just executing a simple x=1 over and over... so yes, it seems to be just the groovy part.

Answer (score 0):

With out looking at your entire project it isn't possible to tell if the bottleneck is constantly loading and compiling Groovy code, or if it is running the actual Groovy code once it's loaded. If your issue is that once the Groovy code is loaded in your game it is taking to long to execute take a look at [Groovy++](https://code.google.com/p/groovypptest/) I'm not sure how well it works since it's still in early days but if this is a learning project it may be stable enough for you.

Comment: well if you are really interested in taking a look the code is at https://github.com/l00mer/ibengine. Thanks for the Groovy++ link. I'll check that out. Running samples.java will execute the code with only java. If you run samples.java with any arg it will run scripted ai and it is painfully slow.